# Terraform - List to String to create the azure subscription list

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating a new custom Azure role and trying to pass all the subscription IDs to the assignable scope argument using the below code but I am having issues converting from list to string with the correct string format. Here is the role definition module doc - https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/role_definition.html

Appreciate any inputs or guidance!

```
locals {
 subscription_list  = formatlist("/subscriptions/%s", data.azurerm_subscriptions.all.subscriptions[*].subscription_id)
  quoted_subsciption_list = formatlist("%q", local.sub_list)
}
```

When I use join function to convert this into a string using the below code, 
`join(",", local.quoted_subsciption_list)`

I am getting the output as **"\"/subscriptions/7yed1028-4525-4533-b608-fb74c2a9c1rr\",\"/subscriptions/7uef9fad-dabf-8icf-8379-a3df99e7613c\",**

I want the output to be **"/subscriptions/7yed1028-4525-4533-b608-fb74c2a9c1rr", "/subscriptions/7uef9fad-dabf-8icf-8379-a3df99e7613c".**```
locals {
 subscription_list  = formatlist("/subscriptions/%s", data.azurerm_subscriptions.all.subscriptions[*].subscription_id)
  quoted_subsciption_list = formatlist("%q", local.sub_list)
}

````
When I use join function to convert this into a string using the below code, 
```join(",", local.quoted_subsciption_list)```

I am getting the output as **"\"/subscriptions/7yed1028-4525-4533-b608-fb74c2a9c1rr\",\"/subscriptions/7uef9fad-dabf-8icf-8379-a3df99e7613c\",**

I want the output to be **"/subscriptions/7yed1028-4525-4533-b608-fb74c2a9c1rr", "/subscriptions/7uef9fad-dabf-8icf-8379-a3df99e7613c".**
````

Answer (score 0):

**local.subscription_list** is already **list(string)** which is what azurerm_role_definition's **assignable_scopes** needs, so you can do this in your **azurerm_role_definition** resource block:

```
assignable_scopes = local.subsciption_list
```